# How to migrate SVN repository with no history?

Tags: svn

I see a massively answered question on here about how to migrate a repository **with** history, but I have a project **without history** (newly developed, not yet deployed, everything in TRUNK).  More importantly, the SVN admin won't use the higher level commands (the commands, I suspect, one would use to migrate with history) to move the project, and I don't have authority.

So what I'd like to do is, more or less, copy the code out of the repo_1 subdir TRUNK without any checkouts, and place the code into the new, empty repo_2 subdir TRUNK.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

========================

Despite the upvoted answers below, the easiest solution for this non-command-line kind of developer was suggested by the first comment below.  This is what I did.

1. Copied from current Workspace using Windows Explorer and pasted copy into a different
   hold folder
2. Deleted the .svn folder in the new copy
3. Deleted old project from Project view (checkbox: delete underlying files checked) [Which also deletes it, by definition from current Workspace]
4. Imported from hold folder as "existing project" into current Workspace
5. Remove old SVN repository from SVN Repository view
6. Add new SVN repository to SVN Repository view
7. Check in new project into new SVN Repository

Comment: What additional metadata do you want to retain, over that from simply `svn export`ing the code from one place, and `svn add`ing it in the other?

Answer (score 4):

Three ways of doing this:

Using `svn.exe` client:

1. [`svn export <url-to-old-repo>`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html),
2. [`svn import <url-to-new-repo>`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.import.html).

Using `svnadmin dump` and `svnadmin load` on server-side (requires full read access to the repository on filesystem):

1. [`svnadmin dump path-to-original-repository -r HEAD > MyDump.svndump`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.dump.html)
2. [`svnadmin create NEWREPOSITORYNAME`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.create.html)
3. [`svnadmin load NEWREPOSITORYNAME < MyDump.svndump`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.load.html)

You may want to use [`--parent-dir DIR`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnadmin.html#svn.ref.svnadmin.sw.parent_dir) argument with `svnadmin load` command to load the dump to some other path than the / root of the new repository.

Using [`svnrdump`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate.svnrdump) tool (available in Subversion 1.7+). The tool "mimics"
`svnadmin dump` and `svnadmin load` functionality, but operates remotely. You are not required to have read / write filesystem access to original and target repositories as tool operates remotely like Subversion client, e.g. over HTTPS protocol. So you need to have Read access to original repository and Read / Write to the target one.

Comment: Only the second option requires you to have admin access. The thirds and the first one doesn't.

Comment: Don't have permissions/authority to do those.

Answer (score 0):

- checkout code from one repository
- remove svn metadata `find . -name '.svn' | xargs rm -rf`
- import source in new repository

Comment: Or, to save step 2, use "export" instead of "checkout".